# System restore with no mouse or keyboard

Tags: windows-7, usb, drivers, system-restore

I accidentally installed some USB drivers to my Windows 7 system, they were the wrong ones and now my keyboard and mouse won't work. A system restore would get rid of them, but obviously I can't control my computer to make that happen.

Keyboard and mouse still work before windows has loaded, in the BIOS and boot system, so can I do anything from there?
I've already tried booting into another OS, accessing my windows filesystem and deleting the Program Files entry, but it didnt work so they must go deeper than that.
Or could i launch it from a remote machine? I've got some VNC server insalled so if i could get that running that could work.

Comment: Your own idea there, VNC, is  an excellent idea since it's installed. Certainly.  or mstsc/remote desktop if it was installed.  Ps2 is another good option if you have the ports.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### A few suggestions:

---

Have you tried going in to safe mode? If you're lucky the bad drivers will not load, and you'll have control to be able to launch a restore.

To get to safe mode:
Repeatedly press <kbd>F8</kbd> immediately after the BIOS screens disappears and you should get a menu up to select the mode you require.

---

Try booting with a Windows 7 install disk.

I'm *fairly* sure it has a system restore option on it, so you can restore directly without having to boot the unworkable system.

---

Connect a PS2 keyboard/mouse or use a USB-to-PS2 adapter to connect your current hardware to the PS2 ports.

Comment: The install disc fixed it. Can't believe i didn't think of it.. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

I just spent two hours trying to solve the same problem (keyboard and mouse shut down during system recovery, even ps2 connection doesn't work) and for some reason moving the USB mouse and keyboard from the 3.0 ports to the 2.0 ports solved all of my problems. I was able to do system restore and it fixed whatever issue I had in about a minute.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a logon password and you can't log into safe mode.

1. Restart pc
2. Press <kbd>f8</kbd>
3. click top entry it say use recovery options on somthing like that it will be highlighted just above were it say saf mode so you should just be able to press <kbd>return</kbd> key after <kbd>f8</kbd>  window apears then it will prompt you for keyboard imput default drivers just click next it will be highlighted us or what ever language u installed.
4. Log into windows
5. Then next window press repair pc then click advance
6. It say advance options in blue letters about half way down on window it will scan your pc for restore points and backup sets wait till its done then pick a restore point

Comment: So how is it done.  You said you can't do it with F8 ( which hasn't been how you access this menu since Windows 8 was released ) but don't explain in detail how you access it.